# Including function code snippet form a groovy file in JMeter groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I have a big Groovy script in JMeter and I want few methods to be re-used in different places of my script. Below is what I tried.

This is a groovy script where I have written a function that I want to call from Jmeter.

**Tools.groovy**

```
public void AssertValuesF(float Expected, float Actual, String PassMessage, String FailureMessage){
        if(Expected==Actual){
                log.info("****Assertion Successful****");
                log.info("Actual: "+Actual+" Expected: "+Expected +"\n");
                log.info(PassMessage);

        }
        else{
              vars.put("AssertionFailure","true");             
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
            vars.put("FailureMsg",vars.get("FailureMsg") + "\n****ASSERTION FAILURE****** \n"+FailureMessage + " ||  EXPECTED: "+ Expected + " || ACTUAL: "+Actual + "\n"); 

          log.info("****ASSERTION FAILURE******");
         // AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("****Assertion Failure****** "+FailureMessage + " Expected: "+ Expected + " Actual: "+Actual+"\n");
           log.info(FailureMessage);               
            log.info("Actual: "+Actual+"Expected: "+Expected);
        }
    }
```

Below is my JMeter Groovy code where I am calling the function.

```
    File sourceFile = new File("D://TestScript//Tools.groovy");
    Class groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile);
    GroovyObject myObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
myObject.AssertValues("s","s","asdf","asdf");
```

The output gives this error, `javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: Tools`

This is probably because of 'log' object not available from Groovy. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log` shorthand is available only for [JSR223 Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223),  in order to be able to use it you need to define it manually like it's done in [JSR223TestElement](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/JSR223TestElement.java#L127) class

So amend your code to look like:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

public void AssertValuesF(float Expected, float Actual, String PassMessage, String FailureMessage) {
    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    if (Expected == Actual) {
        log.info("****Assertion Successful****");
        log.info("Actual: " + Actual + " Expected: " + Expected + "\n");
        log.info(PassMessage);

    } else {
        vars.put("AssertionFailure", "true");
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        vars.put("FailureMsg", vars.get("FailureMsg") + "\n****ASSERTION FAILURE****** \n" + FailureMessage + " ||  EXPECTED: " + Expected + " || ACTUAL: " + Actual + "\n");

        log.info("****ASSERTION FAILURE******");
        // AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("****Assertion Failure****** "+FailureMessage + " Expected: "+ Expected + " Actual: "+Actual+"\n");
        log.info(FailureMessage);
        log.info("Actual: " + Actual + "Expected: " + Expected);
    }
}
```

And you will be able to use it from Groovy scripts your way:

[image: JMeter Groovy Custom Assertion]

Also be aware that there is `groovy.utilities` property which can be used to re-use your custom scripts in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), you will need either add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
groovy.utilities=D:/TestScript/Tools.groovy
```

or pass it via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jgroovy.utilities=D:/TestScript/Tools.groovy -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)